Auto Increment of Number With Alphabets in front for invoicing
Im developing a invoice software with excel
i wrote the code in macros
Sub CreateNewInvoice()
  Dim invno As Long

invno = Range("C3")
Range("C4:D4,C8:D8,B11:C11,B20:G36").ClearContents

MsgBox "Your next inovice number is " & invno + 1

Range("C3") = invno + 1
Range("B11").Select

ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

also i have created the switch button to run this code to have next invoice number
when i run this code it will give the next invoice number
what i need now is
please tell the code to add alphabets for my code
like i need prefix of "TN2425YP" after that invoice number need to increase
example TN2425YP1
after clicking new invoice
it need to be changed in TN2425YP2 like this
Please help me what i need to change
VBA CODE for this in macros
to increase invoice number with alphabets

With the same technic as in the MsgBox

Just do MsgBox "Your next inovice number is TN2425YP" & invno + 1

Just replace this line
invno = Range("C3")

with this
invno = "TN2425YP" & val( Replace( Range("C3"),"TN2425YP",""))+1


TYPE MISMATCH ERROR COMING SIR

Can you show us what is the value in range (C3) when the error occurred. The value at C3 in the first run  must be  "TN2425YP1" for this to work and you should use full qualified address like Worksheets("Sheet-Name").Range("C3").Value and not Rang("C3")

i set the value as TN2425YP1 but it shows me same error

where i should need to update the qualified address sir

qualified address  mean that you write in the function ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet-Name").Range("C3").Value instead of just Rang("C3") . can you try the function on a different cell , I tested the function and it works for me. so it do not  understand where the error came from ?

You can even try invno = "TN2425YP" & val( Replace( "TN2425YP5","TN2425YP",""))+1 to see if the error occurs.
